# How to make MATCH result mandatory with Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a cypher looking like this:

```
CREATE

(a:LabelA {
    uid: "01"
})

WITH * MATCH
    (b:LabelB {uid: "02"})

MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b)
```

If I do not have any node with uid `"02"` I would like to get an error. This cypher passes, but the relation `(a)-[:RELATION]-(b)` is not created (since the node 'b' does not exist).

How can I solve this?

Comment: should the b node absolutely exist ?

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen: Yes, otherwise I would like to receive an error.

Comment: you can't receive an error, but you can create the node if it doesn't exist, is it that you want ?

Comment: Nope, I need an error.

Answer (score 0):

Ter is no way to get error with your scenario if you are directly executing this query on neo4j. In case you are executing this query through some application via an API, then probebly you can write functionality to throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an error for a `MATCH` pattern to not match anything.

If your code needs an error for some reason, then it should just generate an error when the query response indicates that there is no node with a `uid` value of "02".

For example, suppose you added an appropriate `RETURN` statement to your query:

```
MERGE  (a:LabelA {uid: "01"}) 
WITH * 
MATCH (b:LabelB {uid: "02"})
MERGE (a)-[:RELATION]->(b) 
RETURN b;
```

Then, your code can check if any data rows are returned. If no rows are returned, then there is no node with the `uid` value "02".

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (b: LabelB {uid: "02"}) 
WITH b, CASE WHEN b IS NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END AS nodeNotFound 
CALL apoc.util.validate(nodeNotFound,'Node with given property and label not found!', [404])
```